# Using SQL to increase a field value by a set percentage of the original value

Tags: mysql

How can i set balance to be balance + 2% (two percent of balance)

I have tried to do the following:

```
UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 2 '%';
```

but it didn't work.

Also tried this:

```
UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 2%;
```

It still didn't work.

Comment: Percent is a special sign in queries used for pattern placeholders. Just do the math. `UPDATE users SET balance = balance * 1.02`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply 2% represent 2 of 100%

```sql
-- 2% = balance * (2/100)
UPDATE users SET balance = balance + balance * (2/100);
```